# Can you have multiple channels returned from one refresh/access token?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to find a definitive answer as to whether multiple youtube channels can be tied to one refresh/access token, and if so, if they can be returned by the youtube v3 API as multiple item enteries, or if only one can be returned regardless of whether multiple channels linked to the refresh/access token is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are attached to one channel only. Even if user has multiple channels tied to same account, they pick which one to authorized against during OAuth2.

[More information here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html).